# Getting length of filled column

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

I have some columns in Google Sheets and want to know that how many of the columns are filled e.g 100,220 or what ever.

How I can put this thing formula so that I don't have to count the columns or look up the columns count every time?

Answer (score -2):

You can do this 2 ways

1. By formula in a cell or cells within a spreadsheet
2. By using Google-script for spreadsheets to add a menu item to your spreadsheet that, when clicked executes a script to output the result to a msgBox dialog box on your screen, or output the result to a cell within your spreadsheet.

Both methods are simple, and should require little research.  If you require more help please comment back